# React eliminate dots from import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, path

I am kinda new in the web and would like to ask a simple question.
Basically I just want to eliminate dots from my import. I mean thing like:

```
import Component from '../../container/etc'
```

How could I just start my import from the root? So its would become smth like:

```
import Component from 'container/etc'
```

I used `create-react-app` for set up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `resolve` config in `webpack` like

```
module.exports = {
    //things here
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.jsx', '.scss', '.js', '.json'],
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
            'node_modules'
        ]
    }
    // other things here
}
```

where you directory structure would be like

```
-- app
   -- container
      -- etc.js
   -- api.json
```

so you can import like

```
import ETC from 'container/etc';
import json from 'api.json'
```

In case you are using `create-react-app`, you can create a `.env` file on the root of your project and make the `NODE_PATH` point to the `src` folder (or wherever you have your code) all you'll have to do is write:

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

Create-react-app will read your `.env` file without ejecting.

Comment: Umm how exactly would I do that?
I mean, I didn't really even know where is the config file. (shame on me :( )

Comment: You need to update your webpack.config.js to include the resolve configuration

Comment: I feel so stupid to ask this... But where can I find webpack.config.js?
or I have to make this file? (if yes, then where?)

Comment: Did you use create-react-app to set up react app

Comment: Yes I used create-react-app

Comment: Glad to have helped :-) . create-react-app kind of encapsulates all these configs and will only expose these if you run `npm run eject`.